# php - convert Hour:Minute:Second. to second

Tags: php, time

I need to convert **Hour:Minute:Second** to **second** (for example 00:02:05 = 125s). Is there any build in function in PHP to this or need to do some math?

Comment: the DateInterval class sadly has no function for that, so you will have to do the math

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Is this format based on 24 hours or is can it run past 24 hours, e.g. `42:12:02`?

Answer (score 7):

You can try using

```
strtotime('00:02:05') - strtotime('today'); //125
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/ya9CK2Al)

Comment: I don't believe this is what the user is asking.

Comment: It takes his string as argument and returns seconds, just like he asked. Well, its up to him.

Comment: Maybe, provided the format can not be `42:12:02`. That is *assuming* it's based on a 24 hour clock.

Comment: It works! But if I try to get value from **mm:ss** it returns negative value. :(

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function in PHP:

```
function seconds($time){
$time = explode(':', $time);
return ($time[0]*3600) + ($time[1]*60) + $time[2];
}
```

Example: http://codepad.org/gAjZGtq3

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime` could help. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Alternatively,

```
<?php
$parts = explode(":", $my_str_time); //if you know its safe
$answer = ($parts[0] * 60 * 60 + $parts[1] * 60 + $parts[2]) . "s";
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be something in the [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). But there is no single method. In addition, you'd need to convert your format to a date time object, then back again.

It's trivial to write your own:

```
function toSeconds($hours, $minutes, $seconds) {
    return ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
}
```